# If $|S_1|=n$ and $|S_2| = m$, show that $|S_1 \cup S_2| \le n + m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite sets with $|S_1|=n$ and $|S_2| = m$. Show that

$$
|S_1 \cup S_2| \le n +m
$$

I don't know what does "show that..." mean. Does it asking for a formal proof? The inequality looks obvious to me. If they are separate sets and have no common elements, then  $|S_1 \cup S_2| = n + m$, if they have some common elements, then  $|S_1 \cup S_2| \lt n + m$, not? Please give me a hint.

Comment: The question is probably asking for a formal proof - i.e. show a one-to-one function from $S_1 \cup S_2$ to $\{1,2,..., n+m\}$.

Comment: Ir iis not clear to me what kind of argument is wanted, but maybe you are expected to quote $|S_1\cup S_2|=|S_1|+|S_2|-|S_1\cap S_2|$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it $A_1$ or $S_1$?

Comment: $S_1$, typo sort of, I am used to $A$'s and $B$'s.

Answer (score 2):

we know that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ and such that $|A\cap B|\geq0$ so $-|A\cap B|\leq 0$ by adding $|A|+|B|$ to this inequality the result will obtain.